# Windows 7 will start in SATA RAID mode but not in AHCI

Tags: windows-7, macos, raid, ahci

I have installed Windows 7 on my PC (Gigabyte ga-p55-ud5) with the SATA controller set on RAID mode. After that, I've decided to try to install Mac OS X and to do so I had to set my SATA controller to AHCI.

Windows 7 only starts if I set it to RAID, Mac OS X only if I set it to AHCI.

Is there any way to let Windows 7 boot in AHCI mode without installing it from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 7 doesn't have AHCI drivers loaded by default. Boot with raid, then enable the AHCI drivers then restart and enable AHCI in the bios.
[This KB explains how to.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976), but is not a complete guide.

[See this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/changing-from-raid-to-ahci/4c94f678-6bd1-48a6-b871-8872c841023a?page=2) for additional suggestions if the MS article does not work for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you installed Windows 7 while in raid mode. If you had installed it while the motherboard was in AHCI mode.

I do not have links, but in my experience, when changing the mode in bios it prompts you about that issue and I have had booting issues when it wasn't set to the mode the OS was installed in.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just boot into Safe Mode. Windows will automatically reenable the AHCI drivers. You will then be able to boot normally. This applies to Windows 10 as well.